# Firebase SignIn with idToken or refreshToken

Tags: javascript, authentication, firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication

When a user signs into my app with Firebase auth, I save both the returned idToken and refreshToken as cookies.  When the app is refreshed, rather than making the user go through the sign in process again, I'd like to just pull these stored tokens and re-auth with them.  So I would just provide a token, and the `currentUser` would be the same as it was before the refresh occurred.  As far as I can tell from the [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth) on the matter, there is no way to trigger a "sign in" just from these tokens.  What can I do?  Or does Firebase store its own cookies to persist the `currentUser` across refreshes?

Answer (score 0):

Should have read the docs better, looks like Firebase persists the `currentUser` on its own, according to ["The Current User" portion of this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users).  So basically, I should stop storing the tokens on my own, and let firebase handle it.

Comment: Do you think there is a solution however? I have some GAS app with sidebar + popups, and the user authenticates from the sidebar, but I also need him to be authenticated in the popups which are opened from the backend, so my idea was to transfer the ID token from the sidebar, to the backend, and to the popup, and then authenticate using it, but doesn't seem like it is possible right now.

Comment: @AlexZ I had been struggling with this exact issue for just for too long to mention...I feel like this information is something that should be repeated in their other pages (at least some highlighted text section or something) - the problem with their docs is that a lot of the same type of information is repeated so searching for solutions in the docs can be a real hassle at times.